# Are constant velocity commands produced by local planner from move_base possible?

Tags: ros, navigation, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a four-wheeled differential-drive robot. I have been able to build a map via SLAM where I would like to have the robot navigate about. The robot that I am utilizing does not have precise motor control (cannot translate and rotate simultaneously from specific commands reliably at commanded wheel velocities). However, I have observed that the robot is capable of performing separate translational (no rotation) and stationary rotational velocity commands well. I wanted to know if it is possible configure the local planner such that it only outputs either purely translational or rotational velocity commands at each instance. I am aware of the parameter `use_grid_path` in the `global_planner` node that configures the global path such that there are no curved regions of the path (so only translation or rotation can occur). However, I wanted to know if there is anything within the local planner or any other parameters that I would have to tune in order for this to work. It would be even more appreciative if one could show me some documentation that provides some form of a similar example to what I am describing. Both my robot and the remote computer that it interfaces with are using ROS noetic on Ubuntu 20.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413863/are-constant-velocity-commands-produced-by-local-planner-from-move_base-possible?/) by [Devin1126](https://answers.ros.org/users/61268/devin1126/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2023-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alot is possible if you create your own plugins, but I don't think anything out of the box is going to help you much with that in ROS 1.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2023-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1